# Search for a word in two files and print the the two lines with tabular separation

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to use Python to write a program that takes a list of words from file #1 (contig_numbers) and look for that word through iterating line by line in two different files (#2  annotation and #3 abundance). If the word is found in the two files then the output will
be the line from file #2 (the annotation), a tab separation and the line form file #3 (the abundance).
If the word is found in file #2 and not in #3 then the output will be just the line from file #2 (just the annotation).
The word can also be found many times in the file #2 (see example below)

I present to you the code that I wrote but it seems that it is not working as the way I was hoping for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import re
import sys

annotation = open('annotation', 'r')
abundance = open('abundance', 'r')

with open('contig_numbers', 'r') as f:
   keywords = ([line.strip() for line in f])

new_file = open ('/home/Bureau/test-script/output_file_test', 'w')

for line in annotation:
   line1 = (line) 
   for word in keywords:
      if re.match (r"\b"+word+r"\b" , line1): 
         match1 = (line1.strip())
         for line2 in abundance:
             line2 =(line2)
             if re.match (r"\b"+word+r"\b" , line1):
                 match2= (line2.strip())                 
                 print (match1+"\t"+match2, file = new_file)
                 break
```

Example of the files :
*contig_numbers*

```
contig-3
contig-2
contig-1
contig-10
contig-14
contig-27
```

*annotation*

```
contig-1    out.27-Actinomycetales  gene_id_947 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
contig-1    out.27-Actinomycetales  gene_id_948 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
contig-1    out.27-Actinomycetales  gene_id_949 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
contig-3    out.24-NULL gene_id_3294    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
contig-3    out.24-NULL gene_id_3295    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
contig-10   out.23-NULL gene_id_11670   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
contig-10   out.23-NULL gene_id_11671   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
contig-14   out.23-NULL gene_id_16640   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
contig-27   out.31-NULL gene_id_32333   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
contig-27   out.31-NULL gene_id_32334   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

*abundance*

```
contig-3    4578    29.5413
contig-2    1091    13.6616
contig-1    2608    11.5441
contig-8    8194    34.0362
contig-9    1457    10.5831
contig-10   1236    8.48298
```

An example of the desired output (annotation tab separation abundance) (this is what i would expect if the programs
run correctly) this file is not the output of the program
it is just an example that i presented  :

```
contig-1    out.27-Actinomycetales  gene_id_947 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2608    11.5441 
contig-1    out.27-Actinomycetales  gene_id_948 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2608    11.5441 
contig-1    out.27-Actinomycetales  gene_id_949 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2608    11.5441 
contig-3    out.24-NULL gene_id_3294    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4578    29.5413
contig-3    out.24-NULL gene_id_3295    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4578    29.5413
contig-10   out.23-NULL gene_id_11670   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
contig-10   out.23-NULL gene_id_11671   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
contig-14   out.23-NULL gene_id_16640   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
contig-27   out.31-NULL gene_id_32333   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
contig-27   out.31-NULL gene_id_32334   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Am I right? `file1 = 'contig_numbers'` , `file2 = 'anno'`, `file3 = 'ab'` ?? Do you get any error message? Can you post it here?

Comment: Correct `match2= (line2.stri())` to `match2= (line2.strip())`

Comment: @Pardoido yes it is correct 
i get a lot of errors 
and i thing that the loop does not iterate line by line from the file 1 and the file 2 i want the loop to iterate through the two files and when the match is found to print the two lines separated by tabulation

Comment: "I get a lot of errors" - which errors exactly? Can you provide the desired output for your example?

Comment: @Jasper I added an example for the desired output .

Comment: You have to be more clear on this : *"If the word is found in the two files then the output will be the line from file #2, a tab separation and the line form file #3. If the word is found in file #2 and not in #3 then the output will be just the line from file #2."* ..because I see `config-10` not in `file1` and yet its line in the output has been changed...really not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: i gave an example what the output would look like 
 so it is me who modified that file manually so i would give you an example
the original files are hundreds of time bigger than those examples
and i modified it again so it would look approriate

Comment: please use the same file names in the code (`'abundance'`) and in your examples (file3?)

Comment: it is corrected, thank you for mentionning that

Comment: I still see "file1", "file2", "file3" and "abundance", "annotation" and "contig_numbers"

Comment: @Jasper I changed the file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some hints:

There are multiple unneccessary parentheses:

```
keywords = ([line.strip() for line in f])
```

is exactly the same as

```
keywords = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

and

```
line1 = (line)
```

is exactly the same as

```
line1 = line
```

There are some more places in your code where this happens.

---

You don't need regular expressions at all. Python strings have the handy `startswith()` method:

Instead of

```
if re.match (r"\b"+word+r"\b" , line1):
```

you should write

```
if line1.startswith(word):
```

---

I dont see any code for this requirement

> If the word is found in file #2 and not in #3 then the output will be just the line from file #2.

---

Your code doesn't seem too far off otherwise. You have to be clear what you expect as output and how a computer program can create this output. From what you have written, I have some idea what you might want to achieve and think this might be it:

```
annotations = open('annotation', 'r')
abundances = open('abundance', 'r').readlines()     # read the file into memory, otherwise you'd have to "rewind" the file for each inner loop.

with open('contig_numbers', 'r') as f:
   keywords = [line.strip() for line in f]


for annotation in annotations:     # use meaningful variable names
   for keyword in keywords:
      if annotation.startswith(keyword+" "):    # the +" " is neccessary to avoid clashes with 'contig-2' and 'contig-27'
         for abundance in abundances:
             if abundance.startswith(keyword+" "):
                 print (annotation.strip()+"\t"+abundance.strip())
                 break 
         else:              # Python magic: executed when the for loop is not left by a break, but because the iterator is empty.
             print(annotation.strip())
```

Further assuming that abundances appear at most once in the abundances file, it makes sense to store them in a dictionary instead of iterating the whole file again and again...

And another improvement: store the contig_numbers as a set to make membership tests fast.

```
abundances = {}
with open('abundance', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        contig, rest = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)
        abundances[contig] = rest

with open('contig_numbers', 'r') as f:
   contig_numbers = set(line.strip() for line in f)


annotations = open('annotation', 'r')
for annotation in annotations:
    key = annotation.split(maxsplit=1)[0]
    if key in contig_numbers:
        if key in abundances:
            print (annotation.strip() + "\t" + abundances[key])
        else:
            print(annotation.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for the mentionned issues,
for the last part i don't have any idea how to implement that

Comment: The ouput is expected to be in a separate file so the  program will create a file number 4 to print the line form fil #2 and the line form the file#3 separated by tabulation

Comment: thank you the program worked well.
From what i see, what i wrote was not that far, so i want to know the difference between what i had and what you wrote.
So if you could explain to me the difference of using  startswith function and the regex that i was using and why the regex wouldn't work and the 
function Startswith did the job.

Comment: Regex or not wasn't the real problem, regex would work as well. Problems were that you didn't rewind the file in the loop and a variable mixup (I guess), you checked line1 twice with the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't mention what problem you're trying to solve, since your code runs I'm going to assume the issue is that the output file is empty.

The reason for that is that you're not flushing or closing the file before your program exits. Just add a `new_file.close()` at the very end and that should get you going.

Comment: The programe that i wrote doesn't work 
and it doesn't give me the right output that i'm looking for.
What i'm looking for is to iterate line by line each of the two files #2 and #3 and try to match the words from the file #1 and if the match is found to print the output.
The way i wrote the program it is not working 
i thought using a for loop will help me iterate through two file but it is not working so i'm open to suggestions.